# advice for annotation on either class or method

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I have the following problem:

I have create annotation for Security:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Security {
     Role[] roles();
}
```

I am now annotating classes and methods with this annotation. In some cases the class is annotated with this annotation and specific method within this class is also annotated with @Security with different roles.

How can create @Before advice that will catch either methods annotated with @Security ot methods within classes annotated with @Security, and also to get the more specific definition in case there are annotation on both the class and method.

I obviously need also the content of the annotation as well (the roles).

Is it possible?

Is it also possible in cases that I have inhertience between classes that all of them have the @Security annotation to get the most specific definition?

Yosi

Comment: Aren't you reinventing Spring Security? I so, why?

Comment: I have found spring security to be too complicated for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (native AspectJ code, but you can translate to @Aspect if you prefer that):

```
pointcut secureMethods() : execution(@Security * *(..));

pointcut secureTypes() : execution(* (@Security *).*(..));

Object around(Security security) : secureMethods() && @annotation(security) {
    apply(security);
    return proceed(security);
}

Object around(Security security) : secureTypes() && !secureMethods() && @target(security) {
    apply(security);
    return proceed(security);
}
```